# Confimration not appearing when it should do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A confirmation is not bing displaye after all validation has passed, instead it is showing a validation message stating no students have been selected to add even though I have done this. How can I get the confirmation to be displayed?

Here is an application you can use to see and use for yourself:[APPLICATION](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text20.php)

1. Select a course from drop down menu
2. In `Avialable Students to Enrol` box you will see list of students. Select a student and click on the `Add` button underneath and you will see that student added into the box underneath.
3. Click on the `Submit Students` button at the bottom and it displays the validation message saying you have no selected a student to add to course, but you have done this so the confirmation should appear. This is the problem

The jsfiddle showing the whole code for this is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PhWbm/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for `children` of an element with the ID `courseadd` while the ID you should be looking at is `studentadd`. Try changing either the ID of the `select` or the selector.